# Can I tell VS2008 to ignore debug-time evaluation of my lazily loaded properties?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, debugging, intellisense, lazy-loading

In our .Net application, some of our business objects use lazy loading to access data from the server.  While debugging, if I want to inspect a property I have to be very careful and not "look at" or access those properties because this causes the IDE to try and evaluate those properties, which fails.  Is there an attribute I can put on those properties such that they will still display in Intellisense but not evaluated when the object is being inspected during debug-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try marking your properties with:

```
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
```